# JSON request for Telize GeoIP

Tags: jquery, json, geoip

I was using the telize.com api to show prices based on location. Recently the API was shutdown and switched to a paid service. I'm having some trouble fixing my code so that it works with the paid subscription.

Is there anyone out there who can help?
I think I need to add the API key to this somehow.
My current code is below:

```
<script>
    jQuery.getJSON('http://www.telize.com/geoip/', function(location) {
    //console.log(location.country_code);
    var usprice = '$1,140.00 US';
    var canprice = '$1,460.00 CAN';
    var ukprice = '£1,067.00 VAT Included';
    var europrice = '€1,476.00 VAT Included';
    var swissprice = '1,580.00 SFr. VAT Included';
      if (location.country_code == 'BE' || location.country_code == 'EL' || location.country_code == 'LT' || location.country_code == 'PT' || location.country_code == 'BG' || location.country_code == 'ES' || location.country_code == 'LU' || location.country_code == 'RO' || location.country_code == 'CZ' || location.country_code == 'FR' || location.country_code == 'HU' || location.country_code == 'DK' || location.country_code == 'HR' || location.country_code == 'MT' || location.country_code == 'SK' || location.country_code == 'DE' || location.country_code == 'DE' || location.country_code == 'IT' || location.country_code == 'NL' || location.country_code == 'FI' || location.country_code == 'EE' || location.country_code == 'CY' || location.country_code == 'AT' || location.country_code == 'SE' || location.country_code == 'IE' || location.country_code == 'LV' || location.country_code == 'PL' || location.country_code == 'SI' || location.country_code == 'IS' || location.country_code == 'NO' || location.country_code == 'ME' || location.country_code == 'RS' || location.country_code == 'TR' || location.country_code == 'AM' || location.country_code == 'AZ' || location.country_code == 'BY' || location.country_code == 'MD' || location.country_code == 'UA' || location.country_code == 'GE') { 
            $('#retail-price').html(europrice);

                } else if (location.country_code == 'CH' || location.country_code == 'LI') { 
                    $('#retail-price').html(swissprice);
                } else if (location.country_code == 'UK' || location.country_code == 'GB') {
                    $('#retail-price').html(ukprice);
                } else if (location.country_code == 'CA') {
                    $('#retail-price').html(canprice);
                } else {
                    $('#retail-price').html(usprice);
                }
    });
        </script>
    <h4>MSRP: <span id="retail-price"></span></h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to pass your api key as a header in the request. Considering `jQuery.getJSON()` is shorthand for a typical `$.ajax` call, you might want to refactor your code to pass the required headers. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25012189/2594119) conversation to gain some insights into how to accomplish this.