# How to include AuthToken in header of API Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a Web API 2 project and I have the following code.  I am making a Web API call to get a list of items and then I will display them.  The following code works but now security has been added and I need to add a "AuthToken" to the header of the request.

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.getJSON(uri)
      .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          // Add a list item for the product.
          $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
        });
      });
});
```

How can I modify my code to include the AuthToken in the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue here is `$.getJSON()`.

`$.getJSON()` is shorthand for `$.ajax()` and doesn't allow you to add headers. You will need to use `$.ajax()`.

See this answer: [Can you add headers to getJSON in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25012189/120939)